# Why does chrome.tabs.query() return url as undefined?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to get the URL of a newly created tab.  The domain is added to `permissions` in my manifest.  Here's the simple listener:

```js
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(tab => {
    //  alert(tab.url);  // also undefined

    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, tabs => {
        alert(tabs[0].url);  // url is undefined
    });
});
```

If I add a timeout, it works as expected:

```js
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(tab => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, tabs => {
            alert(tabs[0].url);  // works
        });
    }, 100);
});
```

But using a timeout with an arbitrary duration feels flakey.  What am I missing?

And is `chrome.tabs.query` even necessary?  Am I missing something that would enable getting the url from the `tab` object passed to the listener?

Answer (score 1):

- [Since Chrome 79](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#type-Tab) in chrome.tabs.onCreated you should use `tab.pendingUrl || tab.url` because the URL may be still in process of DNS resolving etc. and it's not shown in the address bar
- Same in chrome.tabs.query if it's called at this moment on such a tab

```
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(tab => {
  const url = tab.pendingUrl || tab.url;
  console.log(url);
});
```

Comment: Thanks.  That does work in `chrome.tabs.query` but still not in the listener.  That's good enough for me though, I can remove the timeout.

Comment: It works for me in onCreated so maybe you're doing something wrong or there's a bug in Chrome. Anyway, don't use query(), use chrome.tabs.get(tab.id, ...)